# pytesseract does not extract text from image

Tags: python, python-tesseract

I am having the following image and trying to extract the text using pytesseract. But, it always returns some unknown character.
**Image**

[image]

This is the code I am using:

```
import pytesseract as pt
from PIL import Image

#Converting image to text
img = Image.open('frame-1ROI_2.png')
extracted = pt.image_to_string(img)
print(extracted)
print(type(extracted))
```

**This is the output**

[image: output]

If I use [this](https://www.imagetotext.info/) online text extraction tool, it does extract the text and returns the correct text.

**Update 1**

I have made this code change and the result is still the same.

```
img = img.convert("L")
img = img.filter(ImageFilter.SMOOTH_MORE)
```

The image now looks like this:

[image]

I have also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50090612/7497127) method but the output is still the same.

Comment: you will have to do some pre-processing of the image

Comment: @Himanshuman what needs to be done for this image? it just contains the text

Comment: Add some padding, convert the image to BW, and apply smoothness

Comment: @Himanshuman i have updated the question. I have also tried https://stackoverflow.com/a/50090612/7497127 but it still shows the same output